# Replace a line in a text file but only where it is preceded by a specific multi-line pattern

Tags: text-processing

My file contains:

```
Pineapple
Apple
Banana
Rice
Grape
Watermelon
Orange
Apple
Banana
Rice
Mango
Pear
Plum
Banana
Rice
Cherry
```

I want to make it like this:

```
Pineapple
Apple
Banana
Rice
Grape
Watermelon
Orange
Apple
Banana
Olive
Mango
Pear
Plum
Banana
Rice
Cherry
```

I am, here, changing from "Rice" to "Olive", but only where the occurrence of "Rice" follows a match of a multi-line pattern; specifically where "Rice" occurs after the multi-line pattern:

```
Orange
Apple
Banana
```

I am open to using `awk`, `perl`, `sed`, or any other tool.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first and then ask about specific problems with your attempts. Also, please admit that the question is homework.

Comment: This does seem like a homework question

Answer (score 1):

Perl does the job quite nicely:

```
perl -0pe 's/Orange\nApple\nBanana\n\KRice/Olive/' input.txt
```

You can exercise and test regexes on [regex101](https://regex101.com).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
paste -d' ' -s myfile \
 | sed 's/\(Orange Apple Banana\) Rice/\1 Olive/g' \
 | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Explanation:

`paste -d' ' -s myfile` takes each line of *myfile* and pastes it serially (i.e., on a single line) separated by the delimiter (a space). Instead of input with one word per line, you now have input with all words on one line.

`sed 's/\(Orange Apple Banana\) Rice/\1 Olive/g'` searches through the input and replaces each occurrence of 'Orange Apple Banana Rice' with 'Orange Apple Banana Olive'.

`tr ' ' '\n'` translates all space characters in the input to newline characters, converting the single line of input back into the original format with one word per line.